# [nvim][tree-sitter] : Enable syntax highlighting on .hbs(handelbars) files

Tags: html, neovim, hbs, treesitter, neovim-plugin

I'm using neovim and tree-sitter for syntac highlighting in files. But on *.hbs (handelbars) file. Syntax highlighting not working. HTML & HBS Shares same syntax. How can i get syntax highlighting on hbs files?

I tried to enable syntax highlighting via ChatGPT. These are the commands i have tried

```
require('nvim-treesitter.configs).setup({
  -- Other Configurations
  languages = {
    html = { "html", "hbs" }
}
})
```

Then i tred this in init.vim file

```
" For HTML
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.html setlocal filetype=html

" For Handlebars
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.hbs setlocal filetype=handlebars
```

But nothing works. On hbs file

Answer (score 0):

init.vim:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.hbs set filetype=html
```

Or init.lua:

```
vim.cmd('autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.hbs set filetype=html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this, one can assign filetypes to treesitter parsers according to the [documentation](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter?tab=readme-ov-file#using-an-existing-parser-for-another-filetype) as follows:

```lua
vim.treesitter.language.register("<tree-sitter>", "<filetype>")
vim.treesitter.language.register("html", "aspx")
```

this means that the "html" parser will be used for files of the type "aspx"